# HTML multiple Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

Please help me !

I have two divs, in each div is a table. How can I change the content of first table by clicking in the second table.
The first table is on the left side, and the second table is on the right side. "Image 1"

> [image: Image 1]

I want to change the content on the left table by clicking on the right table on the "Table 1" , "Table 2"

One more thing, how can I keep the both tables in line when the content of the first table is to long. when I add more data in the first table the tables are changing their position like this

> [image: Image 2]

Comment: You should post the relevant minimal code in the question.

Comment: you can set the fix length for div for table as you need.

Comment: how can I keep the both tables in line
For each  div give overflow:auto and specify width and height

Comment: here is the HTML http://ideone.com/ZhnKKa
here is the CSS  http://ideone.com/n0JX6V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use javascript for changing the content of the left table when you click on the right table.
2. It is the mistake of all newbies in HTML. If you put the example content in the cell that is endless string without spaces there is no way to make the row shorter. If you put there real data with words separated by spaces the browser splits rows automatically. For being sure you can limit the width of the left table by using css.